# Customize IDs into Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Realtime Database integrated in a mobile app and web panel. By default, a unique ID on Realtime DB is generated on this format: **-Lup7ey2xRPO9Owm67xM**

When creating new register through the Firebase panel, i can customize the unique id with GUID.

```
{
  "0a921e40-5959-43bc-b2be-a65f6712288d": {
    "name": "Test"
  },
}
```

However, after call Rest API, with Postman or on my backend, the unique ID is generated by default on Firebase:

```
{
  "-LupIEooOPXAzbc--dB_": {
    "name": "Test 2"
  },
}
```

Is it a possible configure Firebase do generate unique ids on format GUID? Replacing default format?

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database does not have a configurable way to assign IDs.  If you want something other than the default, you will have to generate it from the calling client.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you. But, how i can set unique ID, calling from Postman, you have idea? I tryed call POST method to myproject.firebaseio.com/mycollection.json and myproject.firebaseio.com/mycollection/myuniqueid.json. Both calls, create the default id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the REST API says that using [POST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-post) is the equivalent of a push operation, which always generates that random push ID.  If you want to specify your own name for the node to add, you should be using a [PUT](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-put) request instead and using the client-generated ID in the path for the update.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as correct.